# Interaction with a 2D array in java processing

Tags: java, multidimensional-array, processing

Im working on creating a battle ship style game in a program called processing right now I am working on simply interacting with the board for now. I want the grid cell to change color if clicked as well as print out its coordinates into the console. I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong here, instead of changing color it just changes the whole thing to that color.

```
int col = 10;
int row = 10;

int colors = 50;

//rectangle variables
int x;
int y;

int [][] boxes = new int [9][9];

void setup(){
  size(300,300);

  for(int i = 0; i< boxes.length; i++){
    for(int j = 0; j < boxes[i].length; j++){
        boxes[i][j] = j;
    }
  }
}
void draw(){
 for(int i = 0; i< boxes.length; i++){
    for(int j = 0; j < boxes[i].length; j++){
      x = i * 30;
      y = j * 30;

      fill(colors);
      stroke(0);
      rect (x, y, 30, 30);


    }
  }

}
void mousePressed(){
   for(int i = 0; i< boxes.length; i++){
    for(int j = 0; j < boxes[i].length; j++){
      colors = 90;
      fill(colors);
    }
   }
}
```

Comment: Can you share your fill method? That is likely where the problem is.

Comment: fill is just a built in method in processing

Comment: Your `mousePressed` doesn't actually do any drawing. It just keeps repeatedly changing `fill()` but then changing it again before drawing anything. Only the last color in the last pass through the loop is in effect when `draw` is next reached.

Comment: okay i removed the fill() function so it is just changing the value colors instead. it did not work unforunatly. I also removed the fill() from the for loop in the setup() and placed it above the loop and I still got the same result

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Think of using `fill()` as changing pencil: every action you take after changing pencil will use this pencil.

Here, I modified your code so you have an array just to "remember" which color is where. I commented it so you know everything I modified and why.

Don't hesitate to ask away if you have questions.

```
final int col = 10;
final int row = 10;
final int boxSize = 30;

final color selectedBoxColor = color(90);
final color boxColor = color(50);

//int colors = 50; //use the array instead

//rectangle variables
int x;
int y;

//arrays starts at zero, but are initialized at their "normal" number
int [][] boxes = new int [col][row];
color [][] boxesColor = new color [col][row];

void settings() {
  //this should be here
  size(col * boxSize, row * boxSize);
}

void setup(){
  for(int i = 0; i< boxes.length; i++){
    for(int j = 0; j < boxes[i].length; j++){
        boxes[i][j] = j;
        boxesColor[i][j] = boxColor;
    }
  }
}
void draw(){
 for(int i = 0; i< boxes.length; i++){
    for(int j = 0; j < boxes[i].length; j++){
      x = i * 30;
      y = j * 30;

      fill(boxesColor[i][j]);
      stroke(0);
      rect (x, y, boxSize, boxSize);
    }
  }

}
void mousePressed(){
  //using basic math to know which box was clicked on and changing only this box's color
  boxesColor[mouseX / boxSize][mouseY / boxSize] = selectedBoxColor;

  //no need for these lines
   //for(int i = 0; i< boxes.length; i++){
   // for(int j = 0; j < boxes[i].length; j++){      
   //   colors = 90; 
   //   fill(colors); 
   // }
   //}
}
```

Have fun!